# Google search results are downloaded as a file in Google Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, proxy, google-search

I'm behind a proxy at work, and Google Chrome insists on downloading Google search results pages instead of displaying them.

Whether I try to search from the address bar, from google.com, or from a third-party site that has a Google search form, what ends up happening is that the search results page ends up as a downloaded file called "search" in my downloads directory.

I haven't seen this happen with any other search pages. Yahoo! Search, for example, works fine.

Has anyone run into this before and/or has any ideas on how to fix it or what might be causing it?

I'd try the Chrome support pages, but they're blocked by the proxy...

Comment: I've the same problem, but I've no Proxy. So probably it's not a proxy problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the proxy isn't configured correctly.  It's probably something that your sysadmin will need to look at.  I assume IE and FF work correctly?

Comment: Yep, IE7, Firefox, and Opera all work just fine. No problems with any other web sites in Chrome either.

I work at a pretty large corp, so looking for the sysadmin is a fruitless affair full of paperwork, so I'm just going to make do with Yahoo! for now...

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I'd guess it's modifying the MIME type or guessing it incorrectly...  I'd be curious as to whether Safari has the same problem.

Comment: No, no. It's not a proxy problem. I've no proxy, but have the same problem. I think about virus activity...